# JSF app creates record with all null fields in MYSQL db

Tags: java, jsf

Exception after creating records null and when is gettin all times

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at entitybeans.jpa.MovieFacade$1.compare(MovieFacade.java:65)
at java.util.Arrays.mergeSort(Arrays.java:1270)
at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1210)
at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:159)
at entitybeans.jpa.MovieFacade.findRange(MovieFacade.java:61)
at entitybeans.jsf.MovieController.getMovieItems(MovieController.java:313)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor89.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:302)
at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:175)
at com.sun.faces.el.FacesCompositeELResolver.getValue(FacesCompositeELResolver.java:72)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:116)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:163)
at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:219)
at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:190)
at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:178)
at javax.faces.component.UIData.getValue(UIData.java:554)
at javax.faces.component.UIData.getDataModel(UIData.java:1248)
at javax.faces.component.UIData.setRowIndex(UIData.java:447)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.TableRenderer.encodeBegin(TableRenderer.java:81)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeBegin(UIComponentBase.java:823)
at javax.faces.component.UIData.encodeBegin(UIData.java:937)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:285)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GroupRenderer.encodeChildren(GroupRenderer.java:106)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:848)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1613)
at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:168)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:848)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1613)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1616)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.JspViewHandlingStrategy.doRenderView(JspViewHandlingStrategy.java:420)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.JspViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(JspViewHandlingStrategy.java:209)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:126)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:127)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:313)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1523)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter.doFilter(ExtensionsFilter.java:286)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter.doFilter(ExtensionsFilter.java:349)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:277)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:188)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:641)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:97)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:85)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:185)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:325)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:226)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:165)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:791)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:693)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:954)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:170)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:135)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:102)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:88)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:76)
at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:53)
at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:57)
at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:69)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:330)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:309)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Comment: Somehow I don't think the stack trace is useful, unlike in other questions. Maybe it's just me.

Comment: @Johan, what could cause that exception.. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at entitybeans.jpa.MovieFacade$1.compare(MovieFacade.java:65)
    at java.util.Arrays.mergeSort(Arrays.java:1270)
    at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1210)
    at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:159)
    at entitybeans.jpa.MovieFacade.findRange(MovieFacade.java:61)
    ...
```

You've a bug in a `new Comparator() {}` anonymous class somewhere in the `findRange()` method of the `entitybeans.jpa.MovieFacade` class. It's attempting to access/invoke something which is `null`. Something like

```
Collections.sort(somelist, new Comparator() { // line 61
    @Override
    public void compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
        // ...
        something.doSomething(); // line 65, something is null here!
        // ...
    }    
});
```

To fix this, you need to check if it is not null before accessing/invoking it. Something like:

```
        if (something != null) {
            something.doSomething(); // something is guaranteed not null here.
        }
```

That's all which can be answered based on the information given as far.

Comment: The exception is thrown after the null record is created, that for sure after your explanation, the issue would know be how come a null record can be created. follow up question. Thank You very much.